# delete all columns in sheet containing specific header (i.e., row 1) value

Tags: forms, google-apps-script

Context : I have a process that automatically resests a form by deleting all itemIDs and creating new ones. I would like, in the sheet where the form responses fall into, to delete the columns related to the previous form ItemsIDs.

I have the following code that sets header values in the sheet as "old columns".

```
function flagoldcolumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MYWORKSHEETID')
  var ss = ss.getSheetByName('rawresults')
  var lastcolumn = ss.getLastColumn()
  var range = ss.getRange(1, 2, 1, lastcolumn-1)
  range.setValue('oldcolumn')
}
```

Then new columns are added with correct headers as the new form questions are generated.

I would then like to have a function that deletes all columns of the sheet if the header value is "oldcolumn"

I found and adapted this code that should work, but I get "out of bounds" Error message on the last line of the code "sheet.deleteColumn(colA[i])"

```
function compareNumbers(a, b) {
  return a - b;// I pulled this function out of the MDN website
}

function deleteColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MYWORKSHEETID')
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('rawresults')
  var dataR = sheet.getDataRange();
  var dataA = dataR.getValues();
  var colA = [];
  var re = /(.*oldcolumn)/
  for (var i = 0; i<dataA.length;i++) 
  {
    for(var j = 0; j<dataA[i].length;j++)
    {
      if(String(dataA[i][j]).match(re) && colA.indexOf(j+1)==-1)
      {
        colA.push(j+1);
      }
    }

  }
  colA.sort(compareNumbers);
  colA.reverse();
  for(var i =0;i < colA.length; i++)
  {
    sheet.deleteColumn(colA[i]); // => this is where the error message points at
  }
}
```

I can't get to understand what needs to be changed so that the code would run properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a counter to keep track of the columns that have been deleted because after each deletion the following columns and now 1 less.

```
function deleteColumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')
  const rg = sh.getDataRange();
  const [hs,...vs] = rg.getValues();
  const colA = hs.reduce((a,h,i) => {
    if(h.includes('oldcolumn')) {
      a.push(i + 1);
    }
    return a;
  },[]);
  let d = 0
  colA.forEach(e => sh.deleteColumn(e - d++));
}
```

and here's a shorthand way of writing it:

```
 function deleteColumns() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0')
  const [hs,] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let d = 0;
  hs.reduce((a, h, i) => (a = h.includes('oldcolumn') ? [...a, i + 1] : a, a), []).forEach(e => sh.deleteColumn(e - d++));
}
```

This is a shorthand way of pushing `i + 1` in to a whose initial value is an empty array `a = [...a, i + 1];`

- [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_operator)